# Some questions by learning Redux + react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning redux in couple with react and react-redux. I have no man to ask some tech and style questions, so, I hope that community could help me. There are code snippets below from my study project. The list of questions:

1) How do I correctly dispatch actions? Calling `this.props.showDetail();` in `App` component is not a good way, isn't is?

2) Is this way to describe `connect` correct? As I understand, the first argument is `mapStateToProps` function and the second argument is `dispatchStateToProps` function.

3) Is the way to describe `Actions` correct? And how do I `dispatch()` them in components with handling data in arguments? It would be good if you could give me an example.

4) Can you give me an advices or best practices with this code?

P.S. I'm sorry if there are any dummy moments - please, if you see any, write about it.

Constants

```
export const SHOW_DETAIL = 'SHOW_DETAIL';
export const LOAD_DETAIL = 'LOAD_DETAIL';
export const HIDE_DETAIL = 'HIDE_DETAIL';
```

Actions

```
import { SHOW_DETAIL, HIDE_DETAIL, LOAD_DETAIL } from '../constants';

export const showDetail = (isDetailActive) => ({
    type: SHOW_DETAIL,
    isDetailActive
});

export const hideDetail = (isDetailActive) => ({
    type: HIDE_DETAIL,
    isDetailActive
})

export const loadDetail = (img, name, tags, deg, txt) => ({
    type: LOAD_DETAIL,
    img,
    name,
    tags,
    deg,
    txt
});
```

Reducers

```
import { SHOW_DETAIL, HIDE_DETAIL, LOAD_DETAIL } from '../constants';
import img from '../media/examples/card-img.png';

const INIT_DETAIL_STATE = {
    isDetailActive: false
}

const INIT_DATA = {
    img: img,
    name: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit.',
    tags: ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'],
    deg: 30,
    txt: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, maxime voluptatibus totam itaque debitis in eum inventore hic laboriosam cum animi corporis exercitationem minima dolorem sunt dolorum autem modi et iste, vero voluptatem est!'
}

export const manageDetailActivity = (state = INIT_DETAIL_STATE, { type }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case SHOW_DETAIL:
            return {
                isDetailActive: true
            };

        case HIDE_DETAIL:
            return {
                isDetailActive: false
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const detailData = (state = INIT_DATA, { img, name, tags, deg, txt, type }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case LOAD_DETAIL:
            return [
                ...state, {
                    img,
                    name,
                    tags,
                    deg,
                    txt
                }
            ]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Root Reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { manageDetailActivity, detailData } from './detail';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    manageDetailActivity,
    detailData
});

export default rootReducer;
```

ContentDescription - component where I should call `loadDetail` action

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loadDetail } from '../actions/actionDetail';
import TagsBlock from '../components/TagsBlock';

class ContentDescription extends Component {
    render() {
        const {img, name, tags, deg, txt} = this.props.detail
        return (
            <div className="content-description">
                <div className="cd-inner">
                    <div className="esc">
                        <button></button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="img">
                        <img src={img} alt="error" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="name">{name}</div>
                    <TagsBlock tags={tags}></TagsBlock>
                    <div className="deg">{deg}</div>
                    <div className="txt">{txt}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(state => ({
    detail: state.detailData
}), { loadDetail })(ContentDescription);
```

App - component where I should call `showDetail` and `hideDetail` actions

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Main from './Main';
import ContentDescription from './ContentDescription';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { showDetail, hideDetail } from '../actions/actionDetail';

import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

class App extends Component {
    handleDetailActivity = () => {
        this.props.showDetail();
    }

    render() {
        const { isDetailActive } = this.props.isDetailActive;
        return (
            <div className="wraper" onClick={() => this.handleDetailActivity()}>
                <Header></Header>
                <Main></Main>
                <CSSTransition
                    in={isDetailActive}
                    mountOnEnter={true}
                    unmountOnExit={true}
                    timeout={300}
                    classNames="active"
                >
                    <ContentDescription></ContentDescription>
                </CSSTransition>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(state => ({
    isDetailActive: state.manageDetailActivity
}), { showDetail, hideDetail })(App);
```

Comment: you can do it easier with functional component with no `connect` method by using redux hooks like `useSelector` and `useDispatch` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to develop, the first one is using hooks in redux, you could check the official documentation [here](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks).

I will response your question with second way and it´s the common form:

1. You could call the actions in any component in this form:

   this.props.actions.showDetail();

You missing the item **actions**, if you are using **mapDispatchToProps** you have the object **actions** in your props, if you want to use it, you need to follow the next steps.

First you should import the actions:

```
import { firstImportAction, showDetail } from '../actions/actionDetail';
```

After the class component definition you can define your **mapDispatchToProps** and **mapStateToProps**.

I recommend you define the functions in this form follow the best practices:

```
class App extends Component {
  // Don´t miss define your constructor function

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
   // your component 
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isDetailActive: state.manageDetailActivity
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({
      firstImportAction,
      showDetail,
    }, dispatch),
  };
};
```

In this form is easier use connect like:

```
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Finally I recommend you define your actions in this form:

```
// this is in actions file

/// dispatch actions
export function showDetailFinal(data) {
    return { type: SHOW_DETAIL, isDetailActive: data }
};

/// main action
export function showDetail(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    // In this part you can use axios or other library to do request or other processes.
    // After all the processes you have a response, so you can dispatch the action with your result
    dispatch(showDetailFinal(response));
 };
}
```

In this form you can pass params to the actions, manage the information in the actions and pass the result to update the reducers.

I hope that this information be useful for you.
Regards

Comment: Yes, it's very useful. Thanx you